# What do the colours mean for detached DOM nodes in the Chrome Heap Profiler?

Tags: profiling, google-chrome-devtools

When analyzing heap snapshots using Chrome devtools, I can't seem to figure out what the colours mean when viewing Detached DOM Trees. What is the difference between red & yellow?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a good explanation [available here](http://addyosmani.com/blog/taming-the-unicorn-easing-javascript-memory-profiling-in-devtools/).

From the article:

> Red nodes do not have direct references from JavaScript to them, but
>   are alive because they’re part of a detached DOM tree. There may be a
>   node in the tree referenced from JavaScript (maybe as a closure or
>   variable) but is coincidentally preventing the entire DOM tree from
>   being garbage collected.
>
> Yellow nodes however do have direct
>   references from JavaScript. Look for yellow nodes in the same detached
>   DOM tree to locate references from your JavaScript. There should be a
>   chain of properties leading from the DOM window to the element (e.g window.foo.bar[2].baz).

Answer (score 2):

*I have not found a definitive answer, but this seems to be consistently true:*

A red background indicates a detached DOM node that is referenced from a variable in a closure.

A yellow background indicates a detached DOM node that is referenced from an object's property or an array element.

Comment: +1 for observation, although I repeatedly see yellow background on non DOM elements as well.

Answer (score 2):

## Update for 2018

When using Chrome v70.0.3538.77, I found that Nodes had no background highlight at all (yet all the documentation available still refers to it), so [I asked](https://twitter.com/LinguaBrowse/status/1060922408763383809) the Chromium dev team on Twitter.

[From Mathias Bynens](https://twitter.com/mathias/status/1060957241509998592) himself, it sounds like old versions of Chrome had unhighlighted references in some cases too (although this does not apply to my newer version of Chrome):

> In old versions of Chrome, an unhighlighted reference like that meant that the object didn’t have a path to the `window` object via JS objects, meaning it’s retained by a system object or the DOM.

He followed up with [this tweet](https://twitter.com/mathias/status/1060957353468522496):

> The colors are indeed confusing! The latest stable Chrome [Tweet sent on Nov 9th 2018; should be around Chrome v70] doesn’t show colors anymore for this reason, and instead shows icons with an explanation when you hover them.

He provided a screenshot of the new presentation format in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/mathias/status/1060996393219674112).

[image: New presentation format]